# Iterating through JDBC ResultSet for DataProvider?

Tags: java, jdbc, testng, resultset, dataprovider

I am trying to make some data-driven tests using database data and then using TestNG @DataProvider. I have created the below table in MySQL that has the following columns and values. I am trying to use the browser, followed by the username and password in each row to log into a website, for a total of 3 tests.

```
    scenario, username, password
chrome johnsmith password1
firefox janesmith password2
edge username3 password3
```

I have the below code to loop through the ResultSet:

```
    @DataProvider
public Object[][] getData() throws SQLException {

    String host = "localhost";
    String port = "3306";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/qadbdemo2" + "?useSSL=false", "root", "password");
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from credentials;");
    int colCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    rs.last();
    int rowCount = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();
    rs.next();
    Object data[][] = new Object[rowCount][colCount];

    for (int rNum = 1; rNum <= rowCount; rNum++) {
        for (int cNum = 0; cNum < colCount; cNum++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getObject(rNum) + " ");
            data[rNum - 1][cNum] = rs.getObject(rNum);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return data;

}
```

However, it seems it is having issues trying to loop. The tests run, but it is only using each column of the first row as the variables for each browser run. Do I have to use rs.next() somewhere here instead to iterate through the rows? What else is wrong with my logic here? Output/results seen below:

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
chrome chrome chrome 
johnsmith johnsmith johnsmith 
password1 password1 password1 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 26256
Only local connections are allowed.
May 03, 2018 1:17:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
PASSED: doLogin("chrome", "chrome", "chrome")
FAILED: doLogin("johnsmith", "johnsmith", "johnsmith")
FAILED: doLogin("password1", "password1", "password1")
```

Comment: You answered yourself. you need rs.next() as a last expression in outer for loop.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Of course you have to call `next()` for each row. And really: you shouldn't use things like first calling `last()`, then `getRows()` and `beforeFirst()`, it has all kind of nasty problems depending on the database, amount of rows, etc. Structure your code so you don't need to know the amount of rows ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks. I understand about not wanting to do last() and beforeFirst(), especially for large data sets. But how else could I get the number of rows without hard coding it in?

Comment: You should change your code so you don't need to know the number in advance (eg use a list instead of an array), which btw is still a bad plan if you're reading a lot of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with this code:

```
    Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][colCount];
    int row = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            data[row][i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
        }
        row++;
    }
    return data;
```

Comment: Please accept your answer so that it closes the question.

Comment: I can only accept the answer after 2 days— will update when possible.